# Scaling the conditioned random variable does not change conditional distribution, why?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$, I know intuitively that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X\,|\,Y]=\mathbb{E}[X\,|\,cY],
$$
where $c$ is some non-random constant. My intuition tells me that scaling the conditioned random variable does not change the amount of information that we have conditioned on. Is there a more rigorous argument? Thanks.

Comment: For any bijective measurable function (in both directions) $f$ it holds: $E[X|Y]=E[X|f(Y)]$. For example, $E[X|Y]=E[X|tg^{-1}(Y)]$.

Comment: I see, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These expectations are computed using a sum or an integral. These integrals/sums don't change because the conditional probability density or probability mass remains the same for a monotonic transformation.

$$f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}$$

E.g. for a scaling transformation the $Y=cY'$ variable will similarly influence the numerator and denominator. $$f_{Y'}(y') = |c|f_{Y}(cy')$$ and $$f_{X,Y'}(x,y') = |c|f_{X,Y}(x,cy')$$ and you get $f_{X|Y'}(x|y') = f_{X|Y}(x|cy')$

---

The notation $\mathbb{E}[X\,|\,Y]=\mathbb{E}[X\,|\,cY]$ is a bit tricky. What does the equality sign mean? You can not replace the expressions on both sides by a single number or a function of a variable. If you write $\mathbb{E}[X\,|\,Y = y]=\mathbb{E}[X\,|\,cY = cy]$ it is more clear.

Comment: Thanks, your notation change makes more sense.

Answer (score 4):

If you are familiar with the [definition of conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra) with respect to a [sigma-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra), the above claim follows from the fact that $Y$ and $cY$ [generate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#%CF%83-algebra_generated_by_random_variable_or_vector) the same sigma-algebra.

If you need more concrete intuition, you can consider the case of discrete $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a cue from angryavian's [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/642034/362671), if $Y:(\Omega,\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A})\to (\Omega',\boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}),$ then $$ \mathbf{E}[X\mid Y]:=\mathbf{E}[X\mid\sigma(Y)],$$ where $\sigma(Y)$ consists of the sets $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid Y(\omega)\in\mathcal B\}, ~\mathcal B\in\boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}. $ If $\Omega'=\mathbb R $ and $\mathcal B\in\boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}_\mathbb R, $ then $\sigma(Y)$ contains the sets $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid Y(\omega)\leq \alpha\}$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb R. $

It is easy to see that the sigma algebra generated by $cY$ is same as that of $Y$ in that, for $c> 0$ (say), $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid Y(\omega)\leq \alpha\} = \{\omega\in\Omega\mid cY(\omega)\leq c\alpha\}.$

In general though, if we have sub–$\sigma$–algebras $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_2\subset \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_ 1\subset \boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}, $ then

$\bullet$ $$\mathbf E(X\mid \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_2) \supset \mathbf E(X\mid \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_1)\iff Z~~\boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_2\,/\,\boldsymbol{\mathfrak B}~\textrm{measurable},~~\forall~ Z\in \mathbf E(X\mid \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_1);$$

$\bullet$ $$\mathbf E(X\mid \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_2) \subset \mathbf E(X\mid \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_1)\iff \int_{G_1} W~\mathrm d\mathbb P=\int_{G_1} X~\mathrm d\mathbb P,~~~\forall~ W\in\mathbf E(X\mid \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_2),~G_1\in\boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_1.$$

Equality only follows if $(\Omega,  \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_1, \mathbb P)$ is a complete measure space, $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_2$ contains all null sets in $(\Omega,  \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_1, \mathbb P)$ (that implies $(\Omega,  \boldsymbol{\mathfrak G}_2, \mathbb P)$  is also a complete measure space in itself) and the previous equality condition $\int_{G_1} W~\mathrm d\mathbb P=\int_{G_1} X~\mathrm d\mathbb P$ holds.

---

### Reference:

$\rm[I]$ Martingales and Stochastic Analysis, *J. Yeh,* World Scientific, $1995, $ appendix $\rm B, $ pp. $459-460.$